# When should I use "SARS-COV2" or "COVID-19"?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

I am writing a formal paper that deals with the broad national implications of the COVID-19 pandemic in my country, and I am stumped as to how to refer to the virus (the pathogen) and the disease (the visible symptoms). During this whole time I was under the assumption that "COVID-19" and "SARS-COV2" were like "HIV" and "AIDS" respectively, i.e. COVID-19 was the virus and SARS-COV2 was the visible symptoms. However, I just went to read the WHO's official documents, and I only ended up more confused than before.

According to [WHO's official guidelines on naming the disease](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/technical-guidance/naming-the-coronavirus-disease-(covid-2019)-and-the-virus-that-causes-it), apparently neither is true. Instead, I'm supposed to use only "COVID-19" to avoid associations with the old 2003 SARS, and when I have to refer to the virus or the symptoms specifically, I'm supposed to use something like "the virus responsible for COVID-19" or "the symptoms of COVID-19".

What is the correct nomenclature to refer to the virus and the symptoms of COVID-19?

Comment: So if you did use only "Covid-19"as per that guideline, which parts of your paper would not make sense? It's not confusing to refer to the virus itself and the resulting illness by the same name, isn't that what we do with other viruses like normal influenza, etc.?

Comment: Not exactly. More like, my higher-ups are demanding me to put extra care in using these terms correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the opening of the guidelines, you should use COVID-19 to refer to the disease, and SARS-CoV-2 to refer to the virus. In a formal paper I would establish these terms at the beginning. I would not expect readers of a formal paper to be confused between the 2003 SARS and the new disease.

Comment: On second read, that's definitely the case and I've been living all this time in a lie. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the answer to this has to do with what the abbreviations stand for.  Covid-19 means corona + virus + disease + 2019.